# How to use method parameter as a plain text in @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In a JPA repository, I need to do a native query, and in this native query, I need to be able to sort by a column. I want the direction of this sort be determined by one of the parameter of this method.

Here is the code I want to write but doesn't work.

```java
@Repository
interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, UUID> {

  @Query(
    value = "SEELCT * FROM student ORDER BY student_id :sortOrder"
  )
  Page<Customer> findAllByKeyword(@Param("sortOrder") String sortOrder, Pageable pageable);

}
```

So `sortOrder` can be `ASC` or `DSC`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM student c ORDER BY c.student_id :sortOrder")
```

Comment: The query I put in the question is an over simplified version of the problem I currently have. The actual query I need to put there contains sub-query and DISTINCT key word. It is something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (student.id) student.* FROM student LEFT JOIN course ON student.student_id = course.student_id WHERE student.student_id::text LIKE '%:str%' OR course.course_id::text LIKE '%:str%') AS S ORDER BY :sortCol :sortOrder`. I',m not sure if this can still apply.

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is need to tell JPA as `nativeQuery` and `Pageble`. You can specify as parameter to the @query

example :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1 ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}", nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I cannot use pageable to sort here. The query I provide in the question is a simplified version of the problem I currently have. My query contains sub query, join, and distinct keyword. I need to do it somehow using a parameter and manually construct the query string.